# where to see attachments in new test plan view - azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

Azure DevOps has removed test plan preview option.

with the new test plan view I can not see attachment which I had in old classic view.

How to see attachments in new plan view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the attachment of the test run shown in the figure below what you want to see?

[image]

About the attachment of test result, double click the specific test result, you can see the attachments on the Summary page of the test result.

[image]

[image]